# How to add command line parameter to pytest command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I cannot find how to add named command line  parameter to pytest command, so I can execute tests with custom parameter available as a fixture.

`pytest --my-parameter`

```
def test_something(my_parameter):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish such behaviour the [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) shall be defined and new session level fixture in combination  with [pytestconfig](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytestconfig) fixture shall be used

```
# conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--my-parameter", action="store", default=None,
        help=("Parameter description")
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def my_parameter(pytestconfig):
    """ Description of changes triggered by parameter. """
    param = pytestconfig.getoption("--my-parameter")
    if param is None:
        assert False, '--my-parameter parameter must be supplied in order to run test suite.'
    return param

# tests.py:
import pytest


def test_something(my_parameter):
    ...
```